# html div percentage - not accurate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

If i have a div 100px x 100px.

And i define 10x child divs that should fit next to each other with 10px x 10px.

Why do they not?

try it with your browser: http://dwaves.de/prozentuale-angaben-check.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Statisches Layout</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
html,body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
.relative {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.fixed {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="relative">
        </div>
        <div class="relative">
        </div>
        <div class="relative">
        </div>
        <div class="relative">
        </div>
        <div class="relative">
        </div>
        <div class="relative">
        </div>
        <div class="fixed">
        </div>
        <div class="fixed">
        </div>
        <div class="fixed">
        </div>
        <div class="fixed">
        </div>
        <div class="fixed">
        </div>
        <div class="fixed">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the link you provided you have a breakline (<br>) after the last `.relative` div. Remove it and it will work just fine. https://i.cloudup.com/8fO-SqAIVV.png

Comment: Works fine for me - ten divs on each line fit perfectly within the 100px box - http://jsfiddle.net/UVB3e/1/

Comment: there are not 10 divs, there are 12 divs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the link you posted, you have 12, not 10 `<div>` elements. Also, you have an unnecessary `<br/>` tag. Fix those two issues and they will fit in one row.

[JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/RZJ6f/) (with `<br>` and two last `<div>` tags removed).

Comment: Argh. Damn it. :-D Often i oversee the obvious. Sry to bother you.

Comment: Happens to all of us. Cheers!